# Need to write a generic method for applying AddHandler to appropriate event

Tags: vb.net, generics, events, delegates

I have an event hub where different presenters in my Winforms app post events to communicate with each other if need be. I am sure there are better ways to do this but this is what I have. Below is a snippet of relevant parts to my question. Everything is working except I need help creating a generic publish method. I do not want to create a bunch of overloads for `Sub Publish`, one for each event. I want one `Sub Publish`, which can ideally take a type (or whatever you come with), perform a cast, and add the appropriate handler.

```
Public Delegate Sub LoginAttemptedHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As LoginAttemptedEventArgs)

Public Class LoginAttemptedEventArgs
    Inherits CustomEventArgs

    Public Property BranchLocation As BranchLocation
    Public Property Username As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal branchLocation As BranchLocation, ByVal username As String)
        Me.BranchLocation = branchLocation
        Me.Username = username
        EventName = "LoginAttempted"
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CustomEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property EventName As String
End Class

public Class EventHub
    Private Shared ReadOnly eventTable As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of [Delegate]))

    Public WriteOnly Property RaiseLoginAttempted As LoginAttemptedEventArgs
        Set(ByVal value As LoginAttemptedEventArgs)
            RaiseEvent LoginAttempted(Me, value)
        End Set
    End Property

   Public Sub Publish(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CustomEventArgs)
        Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = GetType(EventHub).GetProperties
        Dim count = 0
        For Each p As PropertyInfo In properties
            If p.Name.Contains(e.EventName) Then
                p.SetValue(Me, e, Nothing)
                count += 1
            End If
        Next
        'Validate that two events were not called by accident. Each property name should contain
        'the name of exaclty one event, and should correspond to exactly one event.
        If count > 1 Then Throw New Exception("Two or more properties share the same event name")
    End Sub

    Public Sub UnRegister(ByVal handler As LoginAttemptedHandler)
        RemoveHandler LoginAttempted, handler
    End Sub

    Public Sub Register(ByVal handler As LoginAttemptedHandler)
        'AddHandler LoginAttempted, handler
        'Instead of the above line, I need to make this generic to any delegate, not a specific one like LoginAttemptedHandler in this case.
    End Sub

    Public Custom Event LoginAttempted As LoginAttemptedHandler
        AddHandler(ByVal value As LoginAttemptedHandler)
            SyncLock eventTable
                Dim key = "LoginAttempted"
                If Not eventTable.ContainsKey(key) Then eventTable.Add(key, New List(Of [Delegate]))
                eventTable(key).Add(value)
            End SyncLock
        End AddHandler
        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As LoginAttemptedHandler)
            SyncLock eventTable
                eventTable("LoginAttempted").Remove(value)
            End SyncLock
        End RemoveHandler
        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As LoginAttemptedEventArgs)
            Dim key = e.EventName
            If eventTable.ContainsKey(key) Then
                Dim delegateList = eventTable(key)
                For Each handler As [Delegate] In delegateList
                    Dim fn = DirectCast(handler, LoginAttemptedHandler)
                    fn(sender, e)
                Next
            End If
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event
End Class
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Edit: Added a contrived example showing usage below:

```
Public Class SessionController

    Public Sub New()
        OnLoginAttempted(BranchLocation.Manhattan, "testUser")
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub OnLoginAttempted(ByVal branchLocation As BranchLocation, ByVal username As String)
        Dim eventHub As New EventHub
        Dim eventArgs As New LoginAttemptedEventArgs(branchLocation, username, password)
        eventHub.Publish(Me, eventArgs)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Subscriber
    Public Sub New()
        Dim eventHub As New EventHub
        eventHub.Register(AddressOf TestMethod)
    End Sub

    Public Sub TestMethod(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As LoginAttemptedEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Success1")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you considered using an existing library to do something like this?  If I were trying to do the same thing, I'd look at Reactive Extensions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx) to see if it would work.  I don't have any experience with the library myself, so I can't say for certain if it's appropriate.

Comment: That does seem to be inline with what I am looking for and I may check it out in the future. What I have works without having to research how to use a new library, so I was hoping to just post this and get a quick-fix. Thanks for the pointer though

Comment: I am not really following what your requirements are.  Perhaps you could provide two samples of what Publish would look like for concrete cases and then I see a pattern.  With that said and your comment in the Register Method of "I need to make this generic to any delegate", you may be able to construct something if you remember that a delegate is class that contains a MethodInfo and a target object.  Just a thought.

Comment: @TnTinMn  Hey, thanks for even reading this, I know it is a wall of text. I added the publish function for you to see. The reason I left it out was b/c I had to come up with a workaround (making a property to call the event), which makes it very noisy. I also added two classes, SessionController and Subscriber, to show how I have them posting and subscribing, respectively.

Comment: @Rhurac, Please correct if I am wrong, but no Class will ever directly subscribe to `Custom Event LoginAttempted` or any other event of `EventHub`.  All subscription/unsubscribe/Raising is handled by the Register/UnRegister/Publish methods.  I think that you are making this harder than it needs to be by trying the force an Event syntax on something that only needs to be callback.  Events are syntax sugar that is given special status in .Net, but as you obviously know since you wrote a `Custom Event`, it is just a subscription framework based on delegates.  Drop the events from `EventHub`.